JSON serialization with a group by query ... how to?
I have an API endpoint to pull a big JSON blob from one of my models, and it works, but I'd like to improve it. The current implementation is below, and mostly just works using built in associations.
The issue is the second method to pull aggregate data. The query is executed for each instance. Any suggestions on how to implement this to run as a one-shot?
Note! I am stuck with rails 4.2 (sad face)
Here is the gist of my current implementation:
MyModel:
def self.json_report (p1, p2, p3)
   self.includes(:model_a, :model_b, :model_c, model_d: [:model_e])
       .where(model_a: { col_x: p1 })
       .where(model_b: { col_y: p2 })
       .where(model_e: { col_z: p3 })
       .to_json(
           only: [ :col_a, :col_b, :col_c ],
           include: {
              model_a: { only: [ :col_d, :col_e ] },
              model_b: { only: [ :col_f, :col_g ] },
              model_c: { only: [ :col_h, :col_i ] },
           },
           methods: [ :json_aggregate ]
       )
end
       
def json_aggregate()
    end_time = Time.zone.now.beggining_of_day
    start_time = end_time - 1.day

    h = self.model_x.where(time: start_time..end_time.group(:my_model_id)
        .select("SUM(:agg_1) as c1,
                 SUM(:agg_2) as c2,
                 AVG(:agg_3) as c3").as_json.first
    h.delete("id") unless h.nil?
    h
end

I really feel like I should be able to write a simple join, like below, but the json serializer just does not see the fields from the aggregate as far as I can tell
inner_sql = ModelX.group(:my_model_id)
                  .select("my_model_id as my_model_id,
                           SUM(:agg_1) as c1,
                           SUM(:agg_2) as c2,
                           AVG(:agg_3) as c3").to_sql

join_sql = "LEFT OUTER JOIN (#{inner_sql}) t1 ON my_model.id = my_model_id"

If I just add this in a "joins", the SQL spits out correctly, but, alas, no access from the json serializer that I am aware of.
I'm wondering if there is a way to hack the associations to something like this
MyModel:
    has_one :model_x_aggregate, -> { aggregate }, class_name: ModelX.name

ModelX:
   def aggregate()
       # ???
   end

Any tips appreciated!
/*************************************************************/
EDIT - Partially answering my own question
/*************************************************************/
The JSON serializer works as expected when adding the following association:
MyModel:
    has_one :model_x_aggregate, -> { daily_aggregate }, class_name: ModelX.name

But the problem is "daily_aggregate" must be a scope on ModelX as far as I can tell. This sucks a bit, because (also as far as I know) the only things that work in this type of scope are "joins" and "where", at least in rails 4.2.
So I had to get creative! Various approaches had wildly different performance characteristics... any where from ~2000 seconds to ~3 seconds, LoL.
The final form I ended up with for the scope is below, but it still isn't "ideal", it just works for my ModelX situation, which is a time series of one minute data samples (partitioned by day), so it is a bit large. The duplicate "WHERE" / "ON" clause is highly necessary for me here. Doing a "RIGHT JOIN" vs "INNER JOIN" was only a marginal improvement.
Anyhow, ModelX:
  scope :daily_aggregate, -> {
    end_time = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day
    start_time = end_time - 1.day

    inner_sql = ModelX.where(time: start_time..end_time)
                      .group(:my_model_id)
                      .select("my_model_id as my_model_id",
                              "MAX(:id) as id",
                              "SUM(:agg_1) as c1",
                              "SUM(:agg_2) as c2",
                              "AVG(:agg_3) as c3").to_sql

    joins(<<~SQL.squish)
      RIGHT JOIN (#{inner_sql}) t1
        ON model_x.id = t1.id
        AND (model_x.time BETWEEN '#{start_time}' AND '#{end_time}')
      SQL
    .select("t1.*")
  }

I should also mention the backend is postgresql v13.something.
This is "good enough", for me at least. It was a fun rabbit hole.

I am afraid what you have currently presented is invalid code in general and has been overly obfuscated to the point where it is difficult to understand exactly what you are requesting. Can you please correct the code errors and boil the question down to a simple example of input and output?

It looks mostly cromulent after re-reviewing. I forgot the "self" qualifier on json_report def, and misspelled "modle" once. The question is how to replace the method invocation in the json serializer with a simple left join on the aggregate query and have it output the same data with a single query rather than an n+1

Oh, and the colon is on the wrong side of "model_d" in the includes clause.

Made an edit to fix the above mentioned mistakes I noticed.

Oops, one more edit. Missing a couple colons and quotes as well ‍♂️

I would really recommend that you separate between your model and serialization. Once you're doing something non-trivial you really want to add a separate layer such as jbuilder or ActiveModel::Serializers (now defunct but a valid choice for Rails 4.2) to handle rendering the data into JSON. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/better-serialization-less-as-json

Editing to partially answer my own question
